# AVPlayer Video Blank but Hear Sound

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm switching from `MPMoviePlayerController` to `AVPlayer` as I need finer grained control over video swapping. The `.mov` file I was playing with `MPMoviePlayerController` played fine, but after switching to `AVPlayer` I hear the audio from the video, but the video just shows the view background that I added the `AVPlayerLayer` to. Here's how I'm initializing the `AVPlayer`.

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:video];

AVPlayerLayer* playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
playerLayer.frame = self.playerContainer.bounds;
[self.playerContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
```

Then later I just issue a.

```
[self.player play];
```

When the video plays I hear the audio, but see no video. I also tried setting the zPosition to no luck.

```
playerLayer.zPosition = 1;
```

Answer (score 8):

Found out it was a result of using `AutoLayout`. In the `viewDidLoad` the `self.playerContainer.bounds` is a `CGRectZero`.

I had to assign the playerLayer frame in the `viewDidAppear` to match the playerContainer.

Comment: I don't use autolayout but have the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872193/avqueueplayer-shows-black-screen-when-called-from-app-delegate How could you solve it?

Comment: For me the video was a CGRectZero and not visible. It was actually playing, just in a 0.0x0.0 screen.

Comment: @Gary I have exact same problem but with a MacOS project - I hear sound but no video just black window - here is my total code: `let fileURL = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL!, options: nil)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerView = self.playerView
        playerView?.player = videoPlayer
        videoPlayer.play()`   Any idea what I need to add to this to get Video to show?

Answer (score 1):

Since we use AVPlayerLayer (a subclass of CALayer), we need to set the frame

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.avPlayerLayer.frame = self.movieContainerView.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the statement that plays the video:

```
[self.player play]
```

is invoked from main dispatch queue like this (Swift 3):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.player.play()
}
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't help me out.